# how can i rewrite all urls except for a few to https with mod rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl, https

I have made a site with codeigniter below is the current htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I need to add some rules so that the site still works as normal but most URLs are redirected to https. The urls that need to be exempt from this rule are:

/about
/faqs
/terms-and-conditions
/contact-us
/privacy-policy

All of these urls that are exempt should be accessed over normal http

Answer (score 2):

To redirect non-http request to https, use the %{HTTPS} in RewriteCond

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
```

If the request is https, this condition fails and the rule is skipped. Then to exempt paths, you can add them after

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/about /faqs /terms-and-conditions /contact-us /privacy-policy
```

Then finally, the redirect

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://your-site.com/$1 [R,L]
```

You'll want to add these 3 lines above the rewrite conditions for the rule you have above that rewrites everything to index.php